# Вывести элементы массива каждый в новой строке

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вечер добрый! Есть массив `arr=[{id:1, title:...}, {id:2, title:...}, {id:3, title:...} ]`, мне нужно вывести каждое последующее `id` с новой строки, я не использую HTML/CSS. Каким способом можно осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чистый код:

```
arr.forEach((el) => {
  el.id // делайте с ни что хотите
});
```

Вот пример полного варианта

```js
var arr=[{id:1, title:'123123'}, {id:2, title:'123123'}, {id:3, title:'123123'} ]

var items = '<ul>'
arr.forEach((el) => {
  items += '<li>' + el.id + '</li>'
});
items += '</ul>'

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = items
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Это будет в canvas выводиться текст, нет возможности использовать HTML.

Comment: ну так вы с этого и начинайте. А то начали за одно, теперь про канвас говорите...  
вот для примера с канвасом https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddmbRo

Comment: по оформлению текста вот почитайте https://habrahabr.ru/post/140235/